# Testing React + Redux Toolkit with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, redux-toolkit

does anyone have any ideas how I can fix the following error?

> could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider

Here's the component part that fails:

```
const Main = () => {
    const toggleMoreOptions = useSelector(selectToggleMoreOptions);
    return (<div>...</div>)
    ...
}
```

Here's the test suite:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('Main', () => {
    let mainWrapper;

    beforeAll(() => {
        mainWrapper = shallow(<Main />);
    });
    ...
}
```

I've also tried doing this instead:

```
const initialState = { toggleMoreOptions: false };
const mockStore = configureStore();
let store, mainWrapper;

beforeAll(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState);
    mainWrapper = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Main />
        </Provider>
    );
    ...
}
```

Which results in this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleMoreOptions' of undefined

Thank you in advance, I appreciate any insight anyone has...

Comment: Seems like the second one you tried is correct, have you checked if you are properly initializing the `selectToggleMoreOptions` in redux?

Comment: No, I double checked. I've used this configuration with other projects. It's redux toolkit. I'm not sure if that's the issue. Thank you for the suggestion though.